# how to use Jquery to move <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" from top to bottom of page

Tags: jquery, viewstate

to get better search engine spidering, please anyone help me to move `__VIEWSTATE` from top to bottom of .aspx page. It's basically that asp.net will rendering `<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNzIxNTk1NDk2D2QWAgIDD />` at the top of page, so that instead of crawling engine to see page contents first it see a very large `__VIEWSTATE` text.

I used to write my own c# code to move it but during page load if we click some think on page before page finish loading, it will cause all data lost or missing rendering.  I think only jquery is resolution because it wait until page is finish load -> `$(document).ready(function(){ });`

Comment: I'm about 90% positive a hidden input field isn't inhibiting your SEO. The lack of h1/h2/paragraph/keywords/etc. are probably to blame. _(though it's probably better to ask the folks at [webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/))_

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use jQuery to do this.  JavaScript will only move the field on the client-side, in the browser.  Spiders will still see it how the server returned it--at the top.

What you really need to do is evaluate whether you really need viewstate on these pages.  If you're concerned about SEO, then you likely don't, and the best solution is to disable it on those pages.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I decide to keep viewstate in database instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#___VIEWSTATE").clone().appendTo('#theDivwhereYouwant');     
$(".aspNetHidden").find("#___VIEWSTATE").remove(); //remove the first __VIEWSTATE
```

i think this will work..

Comment: Thank you so much, now I decide to keep viewstate in database instead.